# Travis-CI skipping deployment although Commit is tagged

Tags: git, github, travis-ci

I'm quite new to Travis CI, but I found my way through it using their docs. However deploying to GitHub releases doesn't work for me. 
My `.travis.yml` file looks like this:

```
language: java

branches:
  only:
  - master

notifications:
  email: false

before_deploy:
  - export RELEASE_JAR_FILE=$(ls build/libs/*.jar)
  - echo "Deploying $RELEASE_JAR_FILE to GitHub"

deploy:
  provider: releases
  api_key:
    secure: [key]
  file_glob: true
  file: "${RELEASE_JAR_FILE}"
  skip_cleanup: true
  on:
    repo: [my-repo]
    tags: true
    all_branches: true
```

**Here's how I commit:**

```
$ git add . && git commit -m "my message"
$ git tag 0.1234
$ git push origin --tags
$ git push origin master
```

After that, Travis creates the build and skips deployment with

```
Skipping a deployment with the releases provider because this is not a tagged commit
```

When I open up my GitHub repository in my browser, the releases are tagged correctly, yet Travis doesn't detect them as tagged.

Does anybody have a solution for this? I suspected the `branches: only: master` part to be responsible for this behaviour, although Travis **once** pushed a release to GitHub without the `on: tags: true` flag. Afterwards I got errors if I left out the flag saying that I may only push tagged commits as release.

Comment: Could you provide link to repository on Github?

Comment: I didn't see a reason to add it as I basically trunkated my .travis.yml. Anyway, here's the link: https://github.com/minedev/MooseMachine

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to remove

```
branches:
    only:
    - master
```

See https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/2498#issuecomment-48337712

I realize this is a bummer, but I am not sure that Travis can be configured in the way you desire.  You may want to open a ticket - https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/new

UPDATE:

Use a regex for the tags in `branches.only`:

```
branches:
    only:
    - master
    - /v\d+\.\d+[a-z]/
```

Comment: Sorry, but I forgot to close this question. Thank you for searching it, but I already opened a ticked back then. To complete this, it can be solved by using a regex as branch name. Here's the issue I opened: https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/3897 , sorry

Comment: Oh cool, I didn't know about the regexes.  Thanks for the update =-D  I updated the answer for others who may need it.

Comment: Be sure to **check all occurrences of branch filters** in your .travis.yml file. Usually, you can have a root branch filter as in the answer and also a filter within the deploy provider, e.g. `deploy: // - provider: pypi // on: // only: // - master` (`//` denotes newlines). Here, you would also need to add the version regex from the answer to it!

Answer (score 4):

Travis CI differentiates between builds initiated by pushing a commit or pull request and builds initiated by pushing a tag.

> TRAVIS_BRANCH: for push builds, or builds not triggered by a pull
> request, this is the name of the branch. for builds triggered by a
> pull request this is the name of the branch targeted by the pull
> request.
> **for builds triggered by a tag, this is the same as the name of the tag** (TRAVIS_TAG).
>
> Source: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/

So when pushing a commit with a tag this will trigger two builds with different conditions.
**If you only filter your branch names, the build for the tag won't get triggered!**

You should check for tags in the `if:` condition ([here](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/conditions-v1#specification) are the possible predicates):

```
jobs:
  include:
  - # Build debug
    if: branch IN (develop, master)
    ...
  - # Build and deploy release on tags
    if: tag IS present
    ...
```

You can check my example travis.yml for Android apps: https://travis-ci.com/G00fY2/android-ci-testproject/jobs/271171322/config

Comment: Question on this: will it still build on both the commit and the tag commit? Is there a way to only do the build for the tag if the commit was tagged? Having both running isn't too big a problem but it would be nice to be able to only run the tag stuff if the commit is tagged, rather than both.

Comment: From what I know pushing a commit with a tag will always trigger 2 builds. I am not aware that you can avoid that.

Answer (score 2):

Apart of what [@Spain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31282158/55075) said about removing `branches` section (this is required, because the tag build won't be invoked), you need to make sure you've pushed the tags (`git push origin --tags`) so the tag exist on the remote.

The [deployment of release](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/releases) will happen only for **a tagged commit**, not for any other branch to avoid publishing the same files multiple times. The released tag will show under *Active Branches* in *Travis CI* and its build will trigger the release, so you should see the output like:

```
Fetching: dpl-1.8.14.gem (100%)
Successfully installed dpl-1.8.14
Installing deploy dependencies
dpl.2
Preparing deploy
Logged in as X
Deploying to repo: FOO/BAR
Current tag is: FOOBAR-2015
dpl.3
Deploying application
```

After successful build, you should see the files on *GitHub* under *Releases* tab.

---

Please check: [GitHub Releases Uploading](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/releases) at Travis CI for further info.