# Travis CI skip release deployment because this is not a tagged commit

Tags: git, github, continuous-integration, travis-ci, continuous-delivery

I'm trying to configure automation release deployment to Github releases with Travis CI build. My `.travis.yml` file looks like:

```
language: java
jdk: oraclejdk8

branches:
  only:
    - master

before_install: mvn package -DskipTests=true -DbuildNumber=$TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER

before_deploy:
  - git config --local user.name "$USER_NAME"
  - git config --local user.email "$USER_EMAIL"
  - export GIT_TAG=1.0.$TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER
  - git tag $GIT_TAG -a -m "Generated tag from TravisCI build $TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER"
  - git push origin $GIT_TAG

deploy:
  provider: releases
  api_key: $GITHUB_TOKEN
  file:
    - target/tweetsched-dto-1.0.$TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER.jar
  name: tweetsched-dto-1.0.$TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER
  skip-cleanup: true
  on:
    tags: true
    repo: Tweetsched/tweetsched-dto
    branches:
      only:
        - master

notifications:
  email:
    on_success: never
    on_failure: always
```

And what I want - PR is merged to Master branch Travis CI create a new tag in `before_deploy` step and then create new release according to that tag. But when I test it I always get a message in Travis CI logs:

> Skipping a deployment with the releases provider because this is not a
>   tagged commit

There are no any messages about why it doesn't create tags. What am I doing wrong? And how correctly to configure Travis to release new versions of artifact on successful builds from Master branch?

Comment: I'm able to create and push tags manually, but here I'm trying to make this process automatic - each time when I merge feature branches to Master branch, I'd like that Travis CI create new tag from build number and prepare new release of artifact with this version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I had solved the issue and final version of config looks like:

```
language: java
jdk: oraclejdk8

branches:
  only:
    - master

before_install: mvn package -DskipTests=true -DbuildNumber=$TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER

before_deploy:
- export TRAVIS_TAG="1.0.$TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER"
- echo "$TRAVIS_TAG" "$TRAVIS_COMMIT"
- git config --local user.name "$USER_NAME"
- git config --local user.email "$USER_EMAIL"
- git tag "$TRAVIS_TAG" "$TRAVIS_COMMIT"

deploy:
  provider: releases
  tag_name: $TRAVIS_TAG
  target_commitish: $TRAVIS_COMMIT
  name: $TRAVIS_TAG
  overwrite: true
  skip_cleanup: true
  api_key: $GITHUB_TOKEN
  file_glob: true
  file:
    - target/tweetsched-dto-1.0.$TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER.jar
  on:
    branch: master
    repo: Tweetsched/tweetsched-dto

notifications:
  email:
    on_success: never
    on_failure: always
```

Comment: This is just a workaround. To properly handle  the (weird) Travis CI build logic see my answer over here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56447675/3660290

Answer (score 0):

For Travis to consider the tag you need to set `$TRAVIS_TAG` env var. See https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/#conditional-releases-with-on

```
export TRAVIS_TAG=$GIT_TAG
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice! That is not solved the issue, but helped me to find the correct approach. I post final working Travis config as an answer